# List content replacing itself before page publish

Tags: dotnetnuke, 2sxc

Having an issue using list content in 2sxc (13.11.0) and EVOQ Basic (9.10.6). Adding one new list item works fine, when you go to add an additional item to the list, it replaces the first item. In order to add the content, you need to publish the page between adding each new list item (not ideal). This is happening to both content blocks out of the box, and blocks we are developing ourselves.

Wondering if others are experiencing this, maybe it's a bug. Or have I just missed a setting?

We have other EV0Q basic sites we are running with 2sxc are functioning as expected. Though a fresh install of 2sxc (13.11) and EVOQ Basic (9.10.6) allows me to replicate the issue described above.

I can see the items are being added to the relevant Content Type under Data in the Admin section. However, these items are not being displayed, unless we publish inbetween adding said items.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edit: Additional information added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably running into issues with Evoq workflow.
2sxc informs Evoq about changes which puts the page into draft-mode.

There used to be a workaround where you had to install some DLLs to disable Evoq workflow, but in v13.12 there is a toggle in the features to make this happen.

I suggest you upgrade, register your system (free but necessary for activating features which may some day have a security impact) and try that setting:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Would this setting disable 2sxc interacting with the workflow (i.e. Direct Publish)? Unfortunately, the workflow is required for this project.

Comment: I've upgraded to 13.12 and disabled the workflow, which will help us drive on. Thanks for your help.

Comment: perfect. pls mark the question as answered for future people looking for this question.